# Is it possible to get/post parameter "transparently" to action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

Is it possible to post/get parameters that would be not mapped to action's parameters?
I mean do smth like

```
 $.ajax({ url: url, data: {'id'=7,'CorrelationToken'=correlationToken } })
```

where correlationToken could be available only from httpRequest or as "controller level" field? E.g.

```
class myController: ApiController
{
   Guid CorrelationToken {get; set;}
   public void Action(int id)
   {
        // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on why you need something like this?

Comment: Correlation tokens are used to reference messages together. In my case: logging messages. Applying search by one field I will be able to get all related "verbose" and "error' messages together (logged both from web app and client).  It worked for me in WPF and WCF apps.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to write a custom controller factory that
would read the Request posted values and then assign the value to the controller it creates.

Something like this (not tested, but you should get the idea):

```
public class My_Controller_Factory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController
    (System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        string controllername = requestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
        Type controllerType = Type.GetType(string.Format(
            "Custom_Controller_Factory.Controllers.{0}",controllername));
        IController controller = Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IController;
        if (controllerName == "MyController")
            ((MyController)IController).CorrelationToken = Request["CorrelationToken"];
        return controller;
    }
    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        IDisposable dispose = controller as IDisposable;
        if (dispose != null)            
        {
            dispose.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

See here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/732449/Understanding-and-Extending-Controller-Factory-i

Perhaps a simpler way, would be to simply set the value in the controllers constructor.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController()
    {
        CorrelationToken = Request["CorrelationToken"];
    }
}
```

But, the reality here is that you probably don't need to do this.  Your CorrlationToken is probably only used for logging, and it's easy enough to just use the Request itself when you need it.

```
Log.Debug("CorrlelationToken: {0}", Request["CorrelationToken"]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I will check it. I was quite sure that I would get an error if CorrelationToken would not be inculded into ApiController's Action's parameters. Going to check it aslo. For some reasons I do not want to include it into interface explicitly.